# Teradata error 3504 (non-aggregate values must be part of group) when using windowing function

Tags: sql, teradata

So I wrote a query that uses a window function and I keep getting an error 3504 in Teradata, eventhough I'm sure I have the correct columns in the group by clause (all non-aggregate columns).  It has something to do with the windowing function I'm using, because when I comment it out I don't get the error, but I have no idea how to resolve it.

This is the query:

```
select
   n.acct_id as bd_acct_id
  ,n.tran_nr as tran_order           
  ,t.trade_dt - n.tran_dt as days_until_trade
  ,n.n_total
  ,sum(t.trade_ct) as trades_ct
  ,sum(t.trade_gross_am) as tot_trades
  ,sum(t.trade_gross_am) over (partition by bd_acct_id, tran_order order by tran_order) as running_total

  from nnae n

    left join trades t
      on n.acct_id = t.acct_id

  having days_until_trade > 0

group by 1,2,3,4
order by 1,2,3
```

Would appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Comment: The final `SUM`in your select clause is the culprit, but I don't know how to fix it, partly because I don't know what it is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you intend something like this:

```
sum(sum(t.trade_gross_am)) over (partition by n.acct_id, n.tran_nr
                                 order by min(n.tran_dt)
                                 rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                                ) as running_total
```

It seems odd to have a running total, without the date column explicitly in the result set.

Also, I replaced the aliases with the original column names.  Not all databases support aliases in window functions, so this is just a habit I'm used to.

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick, but the results aren't what I was hoping for.  I'll ask a separate question for that.

Comment: @starfly: You must add `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`, Teradata doesn't support Standard SQL's default `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` and returns a *Group Sum* instead.

Comment: @dnoeth THANK YOU!! That gives the exact results I was looking for :)